# Element collection is not lazy loading data

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have my object with element collection lists:

```
public class AppUser {
   
    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Long> appsAndGamesWishList = new HashSet<>();

    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Long> ebookWishList = new HashSet<>();
    
    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Long> appsAndGamesInstalled = new HashSet<>();

    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Long> ebooksInstalled = new HashSet<>();
 
}
```

I override the findById to load just the two list `appsAndGamesWishList` and `ebookWishList`

```
@Query(value = "SELECT a FROM AppUser a "
        + "LEFT JOIN FETCH a.appsAndGamesWishList "
        + "LEFT JOIN FETCH a.ebookWishList "
        + "where a.id = (:appUser)")
Optional<AppUser> findById(@Param("appUser") String appUser);
```

But when I want to get my data using the findById repository, I have the four lists in the reponse.
How could I do to have just the two lists ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are returning `Optional` but asking for `List`, please give some context to your question.

Comment: @code_mechanic the optional object contains the list i want

Comment: `I have the four lists in the reponse` How are you checking this? Maybe while you are checking if the entity has the list, Hibernate loads them. Could you add a debug checkpoint and check if it has all the lists after call to `findById`

Comment: @Raj i use debugger to check it.